# How to highlight angular-material table row conditionally?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I just started with a basic approach so I want to highlight row color conditionally its not throwing any error but does not apply the background-color to the row. I have 5 rows that have `riskINdex` `H` , Any idea what is implemented wrong in below code?

app.component.html

```
<div>
 <mat-table>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="eventType">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Event Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.eventType}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectedRow(row)" [ngClass]="{ 'high': row.riskIndex === 'High'}"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

component.css

```
.high {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: can you output row.riskIndex?  your syntax looks correct, I'm wondering if it's just 'H' instead of High, as you stated at the top?

Comment: Try here: [material row highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417248/angular-4-material-table-highlight-a-row)

Answer (score 18):

**Suppose**, You want to highlight `mat-row` by some model property. lets say highlight when status == Approved.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let entry"[ngClass]="{ 'highlight': entry.status == 'Approved' }"></tr>
```

In the above line of code,

`highlight` is `css` class defined in .css file.

```
.highlight{
    background: #42A948; /* green */
  }
```

The above .css file included in component as following.

```
 @Component({

      styleUrls: ['./expense.component.css'],

    })
```

Comment: Glad it helped you !

Comment: Thank you! this answer should be marked as answered! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"[ngClass]="{ 'highlight': row.status == 'Approved' }">  will do the work. entry not required