# How to deselect single row from mat-table

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I'm using the [Selection Data table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection)

to deselect all the rows we use:

```
this.selection.clear();
```

where selection is an object of SelectionModel class. Now what if I want to remove the selection of specific row from code behind "component typescript code", is there any helpful "angular" statement just like clear() method?

Comment: Check my answer below to select or deselect one row from mat-table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

> this.selection.deselect(row)
>
> this.selection.select(row)

[Sample to deselect 5th row with mat-table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vigvy)

function to do select or deselect specific row.

*Example:* If you want to deselect `3rd` row you can do following.

```
this.selection.deselect(this.dataSource.data[2])
```

This the SelectionModel class [code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/selection.ts#L70)

Comment: thank you, but I have question, is using deselect will remove the row from this.selection.selected array ?

Comment: @Furqan Yes. It will remove. Please mark as a answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ngClass and a flag like selectedRowIndex. Whenever clicked row index is equal to selectedRowIndex, the class will be applied. This link might help you
[Angular 4 Material table highlight a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417248/angular-4-material-table-highlight-a-row/45417497?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa][1])

Comment: thanks, but what I need to do is remove the selection of specific row not highlight it when it is selected.
also my data table is using the multi select feature,  and at certain point I had more than one selected row.