# How to update single cell of table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to update a table cell on hover of that single column, NOT all the columns of same content.this is updating all the columns where my ngswitchCase is pending, but I only want that single cell in the table of that particular row to get updated/render the different button.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="rowData['dataFromJson']">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'pending'">
    <div *ngIf="condition"; then thenBlock; else elseBlock">
    </div>
    <ng-template #thenBlock>
      <button (mouseover)="condition=!condition">A</button>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <button (mouseleave)="condition=!condition">B</button>

    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417248/angular-4-material-table-highlight-a-row

Comment: no its not duplicate. this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're seeing a fragment of a larger template, not the entire template of the component: if there's one property `condition` shared across the component, then of course it's either true or false for everyone. Make `condition` an array (one entry for every row).

Alternatively, make the above a separate component, the `condition` will be then enclosed within its scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the condition is a simple boolean and this snippent is supposed to be in a <td></td> where the dataFromJson supposed to populate the table. I am trying to put buttons intead of data. and when you hover on button A it should change to button B