# Highlight specific line in Angular Material Table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material

I have a angular material table:

> 

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Index</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.index}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Time</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Time}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" >
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="quantity.name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{quantity.name}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[quantity.name]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky:true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
</table>
```

and I want to highlight **specific** line when I click a button in my screen.
I tried to find a solution on the web and I didn't find any way to do that.
If that possible?

Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day,

Amit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 Material table highlight a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417248/angular-4-material-table-highlight-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;" [class.highlight]="row.field===specificLine"></tr>
```

And in the component's style flie:

```
tr.highlight { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I want from JS code to change the td class of specific row (for example the 'row {i}'. That is possible?